# Read RTF file using python

Tags: python, rtf, text-extraction

- reading RTF file using striprtf
- rtf_to_text not able to read URL,what changes need to make in the code?

**Input**
Get latest news update at abc@gmail.com

**Output**
Get latest news update at

**Desired Output**
Get latest news update at abc@gmail.com

**python code:-**

```
import os
from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text
import pandas as pd
from os import path

path_of_the_directory= r'C:\Users\Documents\filename.rtf'
print("Files and directories in a specified path:")
for filename in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
    f = os.path.join(path_of_the_directory,filename)
    
    if os.path.isfile(f):
      print(f)
      open_rtf_file=open(f,'r')
      file_content_read=open_rtf_file.read()
      text_content=rtf_to_text(file_content_read)
      print(text_content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are treating a file as a directory.  your `path_of_the_directory` varaible is actually the path to a rtf file name. Without knowing what specific error you are getting at runtime, it looks to me like that is the problem.  An easy way to fix it is to check to make sure the path is a directory prior to calling `os.listdir` like I do in the example below.

```
path_of_the_directory= r'C:\Users\Documents\filename.rtf' #<--- this is  a file
print("Files and directories in a specified path:")
if os.path.isdir(filename):                              # check if path is directory
    for filename in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):   
        f = os.path.join(path_of_the_directory,filename)
    
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            print(f)
            open_rtf_file=open(f,'r')
            file_content_read=open_rtf_file.read()
            text_content=rtf_to_text(file_content_read)
            print(text_content)
```